Unable to use rename in neovim with ruby lsp
I have tried this with a custom configuration and with the default LazyVim distribution.
When I trigger vim.lsp.buf.rename(), for example in LazyVim with <leader>cr I get a error message stating Language Server couldn't provide rename result.
I am running ruby 3.3.6, neovim v0.11.0-dev and ruby-lsp 0.22.1 installed with Mason.
I have tried installing the lsp as a gem and I have the same result. The lsp logs print nothing new when this error is printed. I am able to use rename in other languages like java or go, so I think it has to be an issue with the lsp and not the configuration, but I am not sure what to try next.
This is what I get when I run :LspInfo
lspconfig:                                 require("lspconfig.health").check()

LSP configs active in this session (globally) ~
- Configured servers: lua_ls, ruby_lsp
- OK Deprecated servers: (none)

LSP configs active in this buffer (bufnr: 12) ~
- Language client log: ~/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log
- Detected filetype: `ruby`
- 1 client(s) attached to this buffer
- Client: `ruby_lsp` (id: 1, bufnr: [5, 12])
  root directory:    ~/Exercism/ruby/port-palermo/.ruby-lsp/
  filetypes:         ruby, eruby
  cmd:               ~/.rbenv/shims/ruby-lsp
  version:           `0.22.1`
  executable:        true
  autostart:         true

Docs for active configs: ~
- ruby_lsp docs: >markdown
  
  https://shopify.github.io/ruby-lsp/
  
  This gem is an implementation of the language server protocol specification for
  Ruby, used to improve editor features.
  
  Install the gem. There's no need to require it, since the server is used as a
  standalone executable.
  
  sh
  group :development do
    gem "ruby-lsp", require: false
  end

I am new to ruby.

I have the same problem. Tried it in VsCode with the same ruby_lsp version (0.22.1) and it worked as advertised.
